# A Musical Rebus

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rebus

So I've never made a rebus puzzle before and I figure I'll give it a try! I hope you all enjoy it!

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]
[image: b]
[image: e]

Can you name the song?

**Edit**: Sorry, I used the wrong image. I've corrected it.

Comment: Ok, I'm no closer to an answer, but googling possibilities allowed me to watch "Me Lost Me Cookie at the Disco", so upvote just for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

> Jungle Love, by Steve Miller Band

As in

> Jungle love, driving me mad, making me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

New guess

> Driving (despicable)me crazy, losing my mind? Maybe *Lose My Mind* by Brett Eldredge?

Old guess

> Driving you(megru) crazy, losing your(gru) mind? I don't know if this is a song but these seem to be the lyrics.

Comment: Good guess but no.

Comment: @PerpetualJ I have edited my answer :)

Comment: Hahahahaha that was awesome! Not it though.

Comment: Another good guess, you're getting warmer! Rethink the first image of the second line.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be

> Rock and Roll All Night, by Kiss?

The lines being

> You drive us wild, we’ll drive you crazy...

Comment: Another good guess, but unfortunately no. In the right era though!